# Android M - Socket behavior when the device enters into Doze mode

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

We are developing a VOIP based application where in we will have to keep the TCP connection alive with the server. In order to achieve this we periodically send keep alive packets to the server. We wanted to know the socket behavior when the device enters into Doze mode. Does the socket connection remain intact or will it get closed when the device enters the doze mode.

Comment: What is sample app behaviour? Java Socket or C socket? Android needs to come up soemthing like IOS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13

Answer (score 0):

From experience (having an app using socket.io) I can say that doze mode stops all network activity except for when in the maintenance window. This means you'll lose your socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all network activity including tcp socket are
gone when device enters doze mode.
You can ask user to ignore battery optimization
to bypass that restriction.